# Fluid Vertical Layout

Tags: css

I've searched through many forums and questions, however could not find anything concerning fluid vertical (not horizontal layout).

I have markup as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
html,body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;}
.wrapper {width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; height:auto !important; height:100%; min-height:100%; position: relative;}
#content {padding-bottom: 60px; /* For the footer padding */ }
.footer { position: absolute; bottom: 15px; height: 45px;}
```

In this case I have layout with fixed height of the header and content. The footer sticks to the bottom.

It's all great, but I want to make fluid vertical layout, so that the footer always sticks to the bottom (just as now) but the header and content have fluid heights: 30 and 70% accordingly.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. The footer has fixed height, and the header/contents should BOTH stretch to fill the rest? (Keeping the 30:70 ratio)?

Comment: yes, i would like to achieve exactly what you wrote!

Comment: It gets tricky when the contents expand too much. For instance, imagine that the height of the viewport is 1045px. The footer then takes up 45px, the header 300px and contents 700px. But suppose now that the header contains a 600px tall picture, and the contents - 200px tall picture? How should the sizes be then? Do you forsake the 30:70 ratio to keep everything on screen, or do you stretch the header to 600px and contents to 1400px? Or perhaps you keep them at 300px/700px and add a scrollbar to the header? Or just clip the header picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this I usually say - to hell with the CSS headaches, let's just [use a good old fashion table](http://jsfiddle.net/hjn3m/) instead!

HTML:

```
<table style="height: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td id="header"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="contents"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="footer"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
body, html
{
    height: 100%;
}
#header
{
    background-color: red;
    height: 30% 
}
#contents
{
    background-color: lime;
    height: 70% 
}
#footer
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 45px;
}
```

It might not be "stylish", but it gets the job done, and will be an order of magnitude simpler than the necessary CSS spiderweb. Also, if the contents of something get too big, it will (somehow, in a browser-specific fashion) resize to keep everything visible, adding a scrollbar to the body if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However I used CSS based on your table principle: I used `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. That did the trick, so thanks for the hint.

Comment: No problem, though this approach might fail on older browsers (say, IE6). So be careful there. (Also, I don't see the point of masquerading a table under other tag names, but that's your choice)

Comment: @Vilx - "I don't see the point of masquerading a table under other tag names", because your markup is incorrectly used?  Because you shoudln't use tables for content structure.  Your answer is a "hack" instead of a proper, semantic solution.

Comment: @Axel - In this case there is no "proper, semantic solution". (OK, maybe in the latest browsers it can be done without tables, I don't know and I don't have time to check now).

Comment: Yes, there is.  Instead you provide a quick 2-minute solution that conveys to the person asking the question, it's okay to cut-corners.  What he is asking for is completely possible without using table markup for layout structure..

Comment: @Axel - what is it then? Using `display:table-cell`? That isn't proper even semantically! You just took a `<div>` and changed it's semantics to a `<td>`! It'll be totally confusing for the next person who tries to edit that code. And unless all the rest of the related `<div>`s (those whose semantics you've changed to `<table>` and `<tr>`) are handled **VERY** carefully, soon you're even going to have an invalid HTML, being at the mercy of the browser's quirks and error-correction to display it the way you need it!

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong.  There's a reason `display: table-cell;` exists.  Using tables for NON-tabular data is incorrect.  The entire purpose of CSS is to tell your HTML how to display and behave.  Anyone with the slightness knowledge of HTML and CSS will surely not be confused as to why a div is behaving like a table cell.  A simple look at the CSS definition applied to that div is a clear indication as to why.

Comment: @Axel - But by using `display: table-cell` you **ARE** "using tables for NON-tabular data". You haven't escaped this "tabu technique", you've just masqueraded it. You're just hiding your head in the sand and pretending that everything is all-right.

Comment: I have no idea how you can argue this.  You are NOT using a table, you are telling an element to act like a table.  There is a huge distinction.  Keep promoting bad coding practices though.  I hope I never run into a project involving your "quick fixes" that produce invalid code structures in favor of not "masquerading" how an element is behaving (which again, is easily discernible to anyone with the slightest of CSS knowledge).

Comment: @Axel - well, exactly what is bad about it?

Comment: @Axel - Uhh... ok? Seriously, yes, I know this rule. I too use tables for tabular data and non-tables for non-tabular data. I don't build my layouts based on tables. This **specific case** just happens to be a rare exception where tables are the only thing that work properly. The more I look at it the more I realize that it cannot be done without tables - not unless you forsake usability in cases with small viewports and/or large contents (where a table will abandon the prescribed 30/70 ratio in favor of displaying everything, whereas CSS will produce unusable overflows)

Comment: @Axel - if you can come up with a non-table layout which does not require Javascript, browser-specific hacks or tenfold increase in complexity, I'll happily delete my answer (or replace it with your solution, if you prefer)

Comment: @Axel - also, that link didn't give a single reason why using tables for non-tabular data is wrong. I admit that in most cases this day and age you can do layout with DIVs/CSS much better than with tables. It'll be simpler, easier and more flexible. Also, it plays better with screen readers and robots, true (though the screen reader problem can be mitigated with aural stylesheets). But if tables are the only thing that can float your boat then... what then?

Comment: "But if tables are the only thing that can float your boat then" - Except in this case, they aren't, which is my point.  You're saying your solution using tables is the ONLY method to achieve what the person is wanting when it really isn't.  Your argument could also be that it's an easier solution that mitigates the work of having to implement browser compatibility.  What I see in your answer is improper, invalid code structure...something which I believe should not be promoted on sites geared to helping people learn the proper techniques of development.

Comment: @Axel - please, prove me wrong. Provide me a solution that reasonably works under all conditions and does not use tables or `display:table-cell` and its ilk.

Comment: *facepalm* - I give up.  Clearly you don't understand why `display: table-cell;` exists in the first place.

Comment: @Axel - I do understand. It exists because somebody messed up the whole semantics/presentation stuff. Semantics is **what the tag does**. Presentation is **how the tag looks like** (or, in the case of screen readers - how it sounds like). Unfortunately, the `display: table-cell` is the lone renegade that crosses this boundary. It doesn't just change what the tag _looks like_, it changes what it _does_. It messes up the whole seperation-of-concerns model. That's why I despise it.

Comment: @Axel - To further clarify - If we accept that `display: table-cell` is normal, then we also need `display:input-type-text`, `display:anchor`, `display:iframe`, etc. Because all those are other possible behaviors that a tag can have. However, since I (like you) agree that semantics (aka behavior) should stay in the HTML, and CSS should only contain presentation, I avoid `display: table-cell` and instead use the actual tag that semantically does what I need - `<td>`. Instead of changing the semantics with CSS.

Comment: @Axel - I just accidentally stumbled across a part in CSS specification that says that the browser must generate fake missing elements (like `<table>` and `<tr>`) for elements with `display:table-cell` and similar. So that makes it a little easier to use it - at least you don't get an invalid document because your `display:table-cell` doesn't have a parent with `display:table-row`. But my arguments still stand.

Comment: You are misinformed, yet again.  Semantics *is not* what the tag does.  HTML semantics is meaning.  A relationship between the purpose of the tag and the content it contains.  It is not how the tag performs.  THIS is why you have CSS definitions that modify the behavior of tags to mimic the outcome of other tags.  So you can write semantically correct, VALID xHTML that can be interpreted correctly by A) competent developers, B) Technologies that use the guidelines to interpret the code.  You're solving a problem by skewing the markup, when CSS was designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @Axel - Ehh... I think this deserves a separate rant on a blog somewhere. I should finally get to making one. In a nutshell - as I see it, there are 3... concerns(? not sure about the correct word here) when writing a webpage - functionality, presentation and semantics. CSS takes care the presentation part, but semantics and functionality are hopelessly mushed together in HTML. CSS, as noted above, also messes with the functionality a little bit.

Comment: @Axel - As it stands, I do not believe in making webpages "semantically correct", because it is excruciatingly difficult (while maintaining sane functionality and design), and offers little to no benefits whatsoever. Yes, it makes the page a bit easier to understand for search engine robots and/or content scrapers, but that's pretty much it. And, in fact, a totally semantically correct page is not really necessary for that - just a few more tips and tricks to keep in mind (and certainly using a table for layout once or twice bothers no one).

Comment: @Axel - and last, but not least - if you really _really_ for some reason want to make a totally semantically correct web page/application, the HTML semantic vocabulary is vastly too limited for that anyway. It's slooowly getting better, but until they decouple it from functionality and expand it by an order of magnitude or two, you can practically forget about it.

Comment: "Yes, it makes the page a bit easier to understand for search engine robots and/or content scrapers, but that's pretty much it." - This is my problem with your arguments.  Semantics isn't entirely FOR robots benefits.  It's the standards put in place by humans so when someone else comes along to edit your code, they don't have to decipher why you're using a table for non-tabular data.  It's like building a 2 column layout, wrapping everything in `<span>` because...span is an inline-block.  Why use `display: inline-block;` on a div when SPAN is already set that way?

Comment: You promote the invalid use of tags, end of story.  You don't use tables for layout structures for the same reason you don't use spans to create column wrappers.  If you want to continue promoting bad practice, so be it.  I see your recommendations as lazy, unprofessional and outdated.

Comment: @Axel - actually, `<span>` is `display:inline`, not `display:inline-block`. But I digress. I do not see this as an invalid use of tags. In fact, I see `display:table-cell` on a `<div>` as an invalid use of tags, and possibly CSS. And that derives not from some ancient web 0.1 religion, but from the direct intents of the web's founding fathers (aka the w3c) and the current situation in the web world. Are you sure _you're_ not following some religious piece of dogma?

Answer (score 3):

Layout:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#header,
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#header {
    top:0;
    height:30%;
}

#footer {
    bottom:0;
    height:1.6em;
}

#content {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:10;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-top:30%;
    margin-bottom:1.6em;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#content-text {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

I also recommend a CSS reset before this.

EDIT
Sorry, first I added fix size for the header, I corrected it, though it seems to be a bit buggy this way. I'm still searching for the best way.

Comment: Doesn't this give the header a fixed size? The author wanted it to stretch to 30% of the page minus footer.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, I'm changing it, sorry. Monday.

Answer (score 0):

For footer you can try this

```
.footer { 
position: fixed; 
bottom: 0; 
height: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I had the same problem, you probably need a so called "sticky footer".

Look for example at http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/, it functions across all browsers. There's also a good article describing how to achieve it here: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: that's only an illusion, if you truly want fixed-fluid-fix layout, this won't work

Comment: this is a simple work-around, there are maybe better solutions around, but the real problem is the lack of support in HTML/CSS for modern layouts (e.g. absolute centering with fluid sized elements needs also some tricks with JS)

Answer (score 0):

### Demo Page - fixed fluid fixed


I've made a quick demo of a layout that is very common:

### HTML

```
<body>
    <header>Header</header>
    <section>Content</section>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
html, body{ height:100%; }
/* you can use "border-spacing" on the body as well */
body{ display:table; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
body > *{ display:table-row; }

header{ height:100px; }
section{ height:100%; }
footer{ height:50px; }
```

*Note that this will only work in modern browsers*